# Dictionary<char,char> doesn't work

Tags: c#, dictionary

**EDIT:**
So, it turns out I can't modify a dictionary in a foreach loop (Thanks for pointing that out).
Here's a messy code which does what I wanted:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<char, char> dicP = new Dictionary<char, char>();
        bool done=false;
        char done1;
        char key, val;
        int ctr=0;
        while (!done&&ctr<13)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("are you done?");
            done1 = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (done1 == 'n')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("please choose Key and Val");
                key = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                val = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                dicP.Add(key, val);
                dicP.Add(val, key);
                ctr++;
            }
            else
                done = true;
        }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<char,char> dic in dicP)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dic.Key+" "+dic.Value);
            }
        }
```

Is there any non retarded way to achieve the same goal (adding an existing value in the dictionary to the dictionary as the key of its own key)?
*Not begging for a code, but for a hint.

Comment: Run in debugger and check the exception message

Comment: What's the exact error message and on what line does it occur?

Comment: for one, it will definitly crash if you pass in strings that can't be parsed to char

Comment: `Dictionary<char,char>` does work. Your code is broken. If you want help you will need to learn how to ask a question. Step 1 is to describe the problem in detail. "It keeps crashing" is no use at all.

Comment: `What's the problem with this code?` What is the error/exception you get?

Comment: Couldn't you copy the dictionary or create a pair of dictionaries? Those would be some obvious ways to go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change a dictionary inside a foreach loop over that concrete dictionary:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<char,char> dic in dicP)
{
    dicP.Add(dic.Value, dic.Key);
}
```

You try to change the dictP dictionary inside a foreach loop over the same dictP dictionary. That is not allowed.

Comment: If you mean to say that there exists a for loop and a dictionary such that that specific dictionary can't be changed in that specific for loop, than you would be correct